# Firebase: functions: Error from emulator. Error: Timeout waiting for emulator start

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Unable to launch `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` due to following error:

```
⚠  functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside the functions directory.
⚠  functions: Error from emulator. Error: Timeout waiting for emulator start
```

Already tried running `npm i --save firebase-functions` as suggested in the functions directory but that doesn't seem to help.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but I was able to solve this on OSX by doing two things:

1. Update your /ect/host file to include the line:

   `127.0.0.1 localhost`
2. Use sudo to start functions

   `sudo functions start`